Winforms project .NET 8 pictureBox Paint
I’m new to Visual Studio using C#. I have created a sample Winforms project on .NET 8 called Test1:
namespace Test1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}

I have placed 2 controls on the Form1; button1 and pictureBox1.
So I double clicked button1 and received
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 

in my code.
I was able to set pictureBox1.BackColor to Red. I'm not able to generate -
private void _ pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, EventArgs e)  

How do I do that? I feel helpless as a newbie. ☹

In the designer, select the PictureBox and press the F4 key to switch to the Properties Window. Press the lightening button on the Window's toolbar to switch to the Events list, find the Paint event and double click it to add the event handler method. See also: How to subscribe to and unsubscribe from events.

Thanks so much for your answer dr.null  It worked!
